# Thermo homework (HW) problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, adiabatic

I do not believe this question can be solved with the thermodynamics knowledge that I have learned thus far, but someone correct me if I am wrong:

> *A 0.2-m³ tank containing helium at 15 bar and 22°C will be used to
>   supply 4.5 moles per minute of helium at atmospheric pressure using a
>   controlled adiabatic throttling valve.*
>
> *If the tank is well insulated, what will be the pressure in the tank
>   and the temperature of the gas stream leaving the throttling valve at
>   any later time $t$?*
>
> *You may assume helium to be an ideal gas with $C^{*}_{P} = 22 \text{ J / (mol K)}$, and that there is no heat transfer between the tank and
>   the gas.*

I think it's most illustrative to start with the entropy balance:

$$\frac{dS}{dt} = \sum_{k=1}^{K} \dot{N}_{k} \underline{S_k} + \frac{\dot{Q}}{T} + \dot{S}_{gen}$$

No $\dot{Q}$ since it's adiabatic, and no $\dot{S}_{gen}$ since I guess we're assuming it's reversible.  One output stream with $\dot{N} = -4.5 \text{ mol/min}$ gives

$$\frac{dS}{dt} = \dot{N}\underline{S}(t) = \dot{N}\frac{S(t)}{N(t)} = \frac{\dot{N}S(t)}{N_0 + \dot{N}t}$$

Solving this gives

$$S(t) = S_0 + \frac{S_0 \dot{N}}{N_0}t$$

For a closed system, my book derives relationships between entropy changes and two of volume, pressure, or temperature changes via the 1st law:

$$d\underline{U} = Td\underline{S} - \underline{P}d\underline{V}$$

$$d\left(\frac{U}{N}\right) = Td\left(\frac{S}{N}\right) - \frac{P}{N}d\left(\frac{V}{N}\right)$$

From here it integrates this to arrive at something like

$$\underline{S}(T_2, \underline{V}_2) - \underline{S}(T_1, \underline{V}_1) = C_{v}^{*}\ \text{ln}\left(\frac{T_2}{T_1}\right) + R\ \text{ln}\left(\frac{\underline{V}_2}{\underline{V}_1}\right)$$

However, this is for constant $N$!  With the helium tank, it is an open system and $N$ is not constant!  So I don't see how I can proceed further.  Without an entropy balance, the mass and energy balances alone are not enough to solve the system.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to solve this without involving entropy:

- Start with the ideal gas law, $PV=nRT$, and solve for $n_0$ using initial temperature and pressure.
- With a constant mass flow rate, $n(t)=n_0-\dot{n}t$ where $\dot{n}=4.5\text{mol/min}$.
- The drop in energy of the gas in the tank will equal the energy flow out, $H\dot{n}=n(t){C_p}dT$.